# Multiple Criteria Match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2021

[image]
[Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/at3vxk2y4ba361gu42m00/VBA-Code-StackOverflow_formula-code.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=dv6a4xdfkwcn3jqfnejf465s3)

**Missing** In above **O3=2**

Hi,What will be the vba code for generation of  data from I5:S17 which I have highlighted with yellow.

I am trying to get data by matching vertical column A & Column B (Criteria1 & 2 ) with horizontal row 2 & 3 (Criteria 1 & 2) with breakdown of Criteria 3 i.e Column D in the way presented in column I,K,M,O,Q,S and so on.

Comment: Probably SUMIFS, but it's really not clear what logic you want to use to calculate the numbers in yellow. Why is I5 = 8, but I6, I7, I8 are all equal to column D?

Comment: Here,In month 1,Product A, Quantity=50 (I2,I3,I4).Now,since the month is 1 it will match month 1,Product A i.e I2,I3 with A and B column,if found both criteria matching then it will take data from last of matching both criteria (Product A & Month i.e I2 & I3) and difference (between I4 (i.e 50-sum of below taken data from D column) in the last .Hence the matched:50=8 (Out of D5=10)+10+15+17. Likewise of other month.

Comment: Ok I see what you're doing there... but then why is M2 = 10? Why is O15 = 95 if there is no month in O3? Why is O15 = 95 but O14 is not 80? The logic seems inconsistent in each column.

Comment: The logic is consistent,if observed properly.Missing data in O3 has now been shown above in description which is 2.

Comment: The logic is consistent,if observed properly.Missing data in O3 has now been shown above in description which is 2.Now,lets come to the point M2=10.Here,M2=Product A and not 10.Since,the missing figure in O3 is 2 i.e month 2 with Product  B in O2 and Quantity=210 in O4,here we have to see Product B(O2) in A column we get match from A13:A17 second match is month 2(O2) which is found in B column at B16 and corresponding Quantity is 45,So we take from 45 and go above untill we get sum equal to O4(i.e 210).So on adding 45+95+70 [(O4-sum(O15:O16)] i.e[(210-(45+95)]=210.So,70 is required from 80.

Comment: Just curious .... in your image sample : i5 value is 8 and M5 value is 5... both are < 10 which is the value of D5. So, what value is i5 and M5, if D5 value is (for example) 3 ? Another case, while D5 value is 10, what value is i5 if i4 is 100 ?

Comment: I5=8 (From D5 which has 10,taken only 8 which makes from Col D : 8+10+15+17 that gets equal to O4 which is 50).If O4 was 45,then instead of 8 there would be 5.Similarly for M5.Interesting,if D5 value is 3 for example,then  I5 and M5 values go negative[ I5=-5 (17+15+10+3-50) and M5= -2 (75+20+17+15+10+3-142) which means either I5 or M5 or Col.D data is wrong.Another case,in Month 1 you have bought total apples 52 Pcs(17+15+10+10) from sum( D8:D5) and during the end of month end 1,you have 100 Pcs Apples(I4=100),Here,I5=-48 (17+15+10+10-100).I hope all queries has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test sub below assumed that the things I asked in my comment will never happen. Also it assumed that column A and column C row value is sorted.

```
Sub test4()
Dim sh As Worksheet, rg As Range, cell As Range, qty As Range
Dim rgP As Range, rgQ As Range
Dim qty1 As Long, qty2 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

With sh
Set rg = .Range("i2:" & Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address)
End With

For Each cell In rg.SpecialCells(xlConstants)

    With sh.Columns(1)
        .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rgP = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical) 'product range column A
        .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
    
    With rgP.Offset(0, 1) 'month range column B
        If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
        .Replace cell.Offset(1, 0).Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rgQ = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 2) 'QTY range column D
        .Replace True, cell.Offset(1, 0).Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Else
        Set rgQ = rgP.Offset(0, 3)
        End If
    End With

    qty1 = cell.Offset(2, 0).Value
    qty2 = 0
    Set qty = rgQ(rgQ.Rows.Count, 1)
        Do
        If qty.Row <> rgP(1, 1).Row Then
            If qty2 <= qty1 And qty1 > qty2 + qty.Value Then
                qty2 = qty2 + qty.Value
                sh.Cells(qty.Row, cell.Column).Value = qty.Value
            Else
                sh.Cells(qty.Row, cell.Column).Value = qty1 - qty2
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            If qty.Value - (qty1 - qty2) < 0 Then
                sh.Cells(qty.Row, cell.Column).Value = qty.Value - (qty1 - qty2)
            Else
                sh.Cells(qty.Row, cell.Column).Value = qty1 - qty2
            End If
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set qty = qty.Offset(-1, 0)
        Loop
        
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It create a range variable from i2 to whatever last column row 2 with value as rg, then it loop to each cell which has value in rg.

Then it create rgP variable as the range in column A which has value of the looped cell value. Then it check if the looped cell offset 1,0 value is blank then create rgQ range from rgP offset 0,1 (column B) which value is the looped cell offset 1,0, else it set rgQ from rgP offset 0,3.

Now we have a range of qty as rgQ which coming from the looped cell.value and its offset(1,0) value as the vertical criteria which compared with the horizonal criteria (the rows) of column A and column B.

Then it take the value of the looped cell offset 2,0 as qty1
create a zero value as qty2 for a sum comparison
and set a range as qty from the last cell of rgQ.
then it do a sum checking by looping.

In the Do-Loop:
A. as long as the qty cell is not the first cell of rgP:
then it do the calculation as seen in the code.
B. soon the qty cell is the the first cell of rgP, then it's the last thing to do a calculation to compare, which either the result is negative or positive.
(I'm sorry I can't describe it well as it's too difficult for me to explain in English).

Please note, the sub doesn't check whether the looped cell exist in column A or not, and also it doesn't check whether the looped cell.offset(1,0) value exist in rgP.Offset(0, 1) (column B).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanx Karma.I do also tried your code.But there I found error on running code.Run-time error '1004' No cells were found On Debug at Ln 16,Col 1.Plz find the link of screenshot file above <Excel> or,Plz find the link  here >https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bPO5Bk_k2q89O9eviflw6K0Uf0Qd01Q0/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I saw your sample file in google drive. I am sorry, It turn out I was mistaken. I thought that column A to D already has data where the expected result is starting from column i to whatever last column. But it turn out, in your sample workbook the expected result is from column A to column D, where the data is from column i to whatever last column.

Comment: My code in the answer won't work. Because (for example in the first iteration of the for each cell) the code is getting the value of i2 (which is Product A), then it assumed that column A (whatever row) has value "Product A" for certain. But since column A in your sample workbook is blank, that's why it throw an error.

Comment: No,I think google drive it is showing blank in preview mode of excel file but if you download it will show data from column A:D.I have done in ms excel 2021.

Comment: Pls find the another link from dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/at3vxk2y4ba361gu42m00/VBA-Code-StackOverflow_formula-code.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=dv6a4xdfkwcn3jqfnejf465s3

Comment: This file in dropbox link given above is working fine as per sample image shown above.Kindly see what problem prompted: Run-time error '1004' No cells were found On Debug at Ln 16,Col 1

Comment: Hi,Kevin,kindly do check your formula : =IFS(
OR($A5<>G$2,$B5>G$3),"",
AND($A5=G$2,$B5=G$3),MIN($D5,G$4),
G$4-SUM(G6:G$17)=0,"",
TRUE,MIN($D5,G$4-SUM(G6:G$17))) as well at below dropbox link >https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/at3vxk2y4ba361gu42m00/VBA-Code-StackOverflow_formula-code.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=dv6a4xdfkwcn3jqfnejf465s3

Comment: Error on > Set rgP = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical) 'product range column A

Comment: @kpi, sorry ... I don't see that you tell about that column A to D  value is coming from a formula. The code in my answer assumed that column A vato D is either a text or a number, not a formula. It won't work if the row value in column A to D is a formula. Sorry.

Comment: Ok don't worry.I was just running your code to either text or number as well.It works in number or text giving with error.Your code seems to be very fine.Only one issue encountered,the above error still comes.I have removed  manually A3:A4 data,then also Run time error 1004 appears.However it gives me the correct answer even after that including the error.Just how to remove this error Ln 16,Col 1.Plz help in this.

Comment: @kpi, i am sorry as I don't know why it gave you error. As you can see the animation in my answer, it didn't throw me an error. Error on `Set rgP = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)` most likely it didn't find the cell in column A which has the same value as the looped cell value. Example : the first iteration, the looped cell value will be "Product A". Since it use "look at xlwhole", if the looped cell value is something like this "Product A " (with blank at the end) and the row in column A value is "Product A" (no blank at the end) it will throw the error.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QB1DBrSlDUuNEXftg4RQxT8mjBSRre1K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In that case it is mismatch due to spaces.No doubt answers are coming perfectly.I don't know why it is giving answers with that error as no change in format has been there.Any how,thanx for your answers.Lastly,try in my file aswell

Comment: @Karma.I did checked your file . The error still comes in my version of excel 2021.I think this issue might be due to Excel Version. I think I have to go with this exception. Great Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I want to insert one column after Quantity i.e after column D,what line of code is required to be changed.My all other columns are filled up.

Comment: Also one row above.

Comment: @kpi, if my sample file not work when you open it in Office 2021 then run the sub, then I don't think it will work also if it's inserted one column after D and one row above. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

All of the information needed to calculate the values was missing from your original question. Based on your follow up comments it seems like you want to do the following:

The sum of each column from row 5 to 17 should equal the value in row 4. Only use values from column D. Start with the last row where the product and month in column A & B match the product and month in row 2 & 3. Then continue using the values from previous rows until the total would exceed row 4.

If the next value in column D would cause the total to exceed row 4, just enter the value needed to equal row 4.

Example Column I:

Target value is 50

Last matching row is row 8.

Row 8 value is 17, total is 17, enter 17 in I8

Row 7 value is 15, total is (17 + 15 = 32), enter 15 in I7

Row 6 value is 10, total is (17 + 15 + 10 = 42), enter 10 in I6

Row 5 value is 10, total would be (17 + 15 + 10 + 10 = 52) which exceeds the target. The value needed to meet the target is (50 - 42 = 8). Enter 8 in I5.

The VBA from another user seems to work, here is a formula to achieve the same.

```
=IFS(
OR($A5<>G$2,$B5>G$3),"",
AND($A5=G$2,$B5=G$3),MIN($D5,G$4),
G$4-SUM(G6:G$17)=0,"",
TRUE,MIN($D5,G$4-SUM(G6:G$17)))
```

Comment: Thanx Kevin,You have clearly understood everything as I expect,but formula doesn't seems to works.Plz apply in Excel file.I have now added the link to file called <Excel File> The link is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bPO5Bk_k2q89O9eviflw6K0Uf0Qd01Q0/view?usp=drivesdk